# Vue: Get reference to element or data bind to alter its class?

Tags: vue.js

I have three nested `v-for` loops:

```
<div v-for="(verse, verse_idx) in verses" :key="verse_idx" >
  <span v-for="(word, word_idx) in verse" :key="word_idx">
    <span v-for="(syllable, syllable_idx) in word.syllables" :key="syllable_idx">
      <span v-html="syllable" :ref="verse_idx + ':' + word_idx + ':' + syllable_idx"></span>          
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I want to change the background color of the innermost `span` element. There are 1000's of these on the page - and I need to reference and change a specific one. Each of these `span` elements needs to be highlighted for one second and then un-highlighted one after the next.

Should I do this by grabbing a reference (as I have above) and then add a class to the element programmatically (jQuery style) or should I do this with data binding which will toggle the class as needed? What is the Vue way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bind class as follows

```
<div v-for="(verse, verse_idx) in verses" :key="verse_idx" >
  <span v-for="(word, word_idx) in verse" :key="word_idx">
    <span v-for="(syllable, syllable_idx) in word.syllables" :key="syllable_idx">
      <span
        v-html="syllable"
        :class="{hightlight: hightlightValue == `${verse_idx}-${word_idx}-${syllable_idx}`}"
      > 
      </span>          
    </span>
  </span>
</div>


data() {
  hightlightValue: ''
}

<style>
  .hightlight {
    background: red
  }
</style>
```

As you can see, you can just change `hightlightValue` in javascript, ex; '12-5-25'

Or you can bind style object

```
<div v-for="(verse, verse_idx) in verses" :key="verse_idx" >
  <span v-for="(word, word_idx) in verse" :key="word_idx">
    <span v-for="(syllable, syllable_idx) in word.syllables" :key="syllable_idx">
      <span
        v-html="syllable"
        :style="hightlightStyle(verse_idx, word_idx, syllable_idx)"
      > 
      </span>          
    </span>
  </span>
</div>

data() {
  hightlightValue: ''
}

methods: {
  hightlightStyle(idx1, idx2, idx3) {
    if (this.hightlightValue == `${idx1}-${idx2}-${idx3}`)
      return {
        background: red
      }
    else return {}
  }
}
```

[Vue Style and Class Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: This code highlights every other syllable at all times, rather than a specific syllable at a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

The Vue way would definitely be to have the highlighting information passed in the data and used. A ref on every syllable on the page would...have a memory footprint, to say the least.

If there should always be exactly zero or one highlighted item, you could have a single `highlightedSyllable` value in the data and read it like this (with appropriate CSS):

```
<div v-for="(verse, verse_idx) in verses" :key="verse_idx">
  <span v-for="(word, word_idx) in verse" :key="word_idx">
    <span v-for="(syllable, syllable_idx) in word.syllables" :key="syllable_idx">
      <span v-html="syllable" :class="{ 'highlighted': highlightedSyllable === `${verse_idx}:${word_idx}:${syllable_idx}` }"></span>          
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

If you needed to handle the possibility of multiple syllables being highlighted, you would need to expand `syllable` to a data structure that included something like a `highlighted` boolean member that you could read.